# Wordpress User Specific Image Gallery?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, gallery

I want to create a wordpress site where user is allowed to login and register for the site. Registered users will be able to submit images which will be shown in a gallery. The main functionality that I want is restricting the user users so that they can only see images uploaded by themselves. They must not be able to access images from other users. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about a WordPress gallery plugin called PixProof?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/pixproof/

It has private galleries.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Table which can record the owner of the Uploads and you can show the uploads accordingly from the Table.

For example, When User will upload Image, One entry will be inserted in the table with Image Identification (Maybe Name) and the owner ID (Owner of the Image).

It's more Complex method, but it's Recommended. You can also use the Plugin named **WP Users Media** -> https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-users-media/.

Let me know if this solves the Question!